# POST or GET for triggering an update

Tags: java, rest, model-view-controller

I have a Spring-Boot application and want to trigger an update method via an endpoint in my Controller class. I can´t decide wheather to use a PUT or POST. On the one hand updating my application via this endpoint sounds for me like a POST but in the other hand it will be a simple call without sending any data, which sounds for me like a GET.

Comment: The question as it stands is a bit confusing. What exectly do you want to update? Some object in your client controller with the, more or less, most recent state the server has to offer or do you want to update objects at your server based on some server logic? It does sound like the primer option is the one you are talking about. In that particular case `GET` is sufficient as you want to retrieve those "updates" from the server. In the case where you want to trigger some server process or script that updates its resources according to some predefined server-logic `POST` is most appropriate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GET methods should be be idempotent and (usually) have no side effects. That makes an empty POST a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Update is PUT, Post is send data, Get is get Data, delete is delete data, in update you must specified na unique like sample id to update the data